# ReportViewer: An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, reporting-services, rdlc

I'm working on an project in which we have several ASP.NET 4.5 applications  hosted by IIS 8.5 running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 with SQL Server 2012.

Every once in a while we get the following error in *any* of the applications when trying to render reports from [ReportViewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘-1073741502’.

Even though some applications run on different application pools, when the problem starts it does for all.

I've done some research and some posts relate this issue with [lack of memory](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/103a5f5d-838b-46c3-ab2f-024c779443ec/an-unexpected-error-occurred-while-compiling-expressions-native-compiler-return-value?forum=sqlreportingservices), [some hung up third party application accesing IIS](https://forums.asp.net/t/1923313.aspx?Native%20compiler%20error%201073741502%20) and [even not having permissions on the TEMP folder](https://forums.asp.net/t/1812668.aspx?%20rdlc%20reports%20error%20after%20deployment). The problem is that none if these is our case.

This issue seems to present more frequently at the beginning of each month when there is more demand of different kinds of reports. Whenever the issue arises, the **only** way to (temporarily) solve it is by restarting the IIS service, or whatever action that results in stopping and starting the service, a system reboot for example. Everything goes fine from there until at any random moment (hours, days or weeks) we get the same error again.

All reports in every application are local reports, but installing Reporting Services could be an option if it solves this problem.

So after running out of options I would appreciate any help you can provide in order to end this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your .net framework installed.

Comment: Is crystal report runtime installed?

Comment: Crystal Reports runtime is not installed and .NET framework's version is 4.7